# AtomicInteger and Compare operations

Tags: java, multithreading, atomicinteger

I'm trying to use an AtomicInteger variable as lock.
So, wondering if the code posted below is thread safe. I know incrementAndGet() is an atomic operation. But, I'm not sure if the subsequent '==' operation will be atomic as well (what if the value gets incremented to 2, by the time I make the comparison.). So posting this question to hear your thoughts.

```
private AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0); //Shared variable
private final int max = 1;

if(count.incrementAndGet() == max) {
  //Do something
}
```

Comment: That said, you're reinventing `Semaphore`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `incrementAndGet()` is an atomic operation, at most one thread will get `1` for result (as long as the AtomicInteger is not set to a value lower than 1). This is guaranteed by AtomicInteger. Although the actual comparison is *not* part of this atomic operation, only the thread which received `1` will run into the `if` block. That's because the comparison compares two values of type `int`: the result of `incrementAndGet()`) and `max`. The AtomicInteger doesn't play a role in it since the primitive `int` doesn't change it's value when the inner state of `count` changes. tl;dr: Your code is equivalent to:

```
final int val = count.incrementAndGet(); // (it makes no difference if val is not 'final`)
if (val == max) {
    // ...
}
```

Java provides many other ways to achieve thread-safety ([Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html), [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html), ...), but since you are referring to an AtomicInteger, I believe [AtomicInteger.compareAndSet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#compareAndSet-int-int-) is more accurate to what you were asking:

```
if (count.compareAndSet(0, 1)) {
    // executed if count == 0
    count.set(0);
}
```

Comment: Much more clear now. I want only one thread to execute some functionality. Hence, I'm checking for the count. Since, its guaranteed that only one thread will see a value of 1, I can safely expect the logic residing within the 'if' condition to be thread-safe. As every operation of incrementandGet() will increase the count, there will only be one thread reading a value of 1. So, that answers my question. Thanks steffen.